# How to emit when events stop coming?

Tags: rxjs

I have Observable from an event of the mouse move.

I want to react when the mouse stops moving - meaning when events from Observable stop coming...

How do I do that?

Comment: depends what you mean by "when events stop coming". a user can stop their mouse for a while and then start moving it again as they please. what do you want to happen in that case? There is no true end to the mouse movement event stream, just pauses of varying lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fromEvent` to watch for mousemove on the document. Then use `debounceTime` within a pipe to wait for the mouse movement to stop.

```js
fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
  .pipe(debounceTime(2000))
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Mouse Stopped: No movement for 2s'));
```